# Jquery datepicker beforeShowDay after initializing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I am setting beforeShowDay after initializing it doesn't work

```
$("#dater").datepicker();

$("#dater").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: renderCalendarCallback
});
```

It will work when I will change and call beforeShowDay for first time

```
$("#dater").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: renderCalendarCallback
});

$("#dater").datepicker();
```

How can I fix this to call beforeShowDay in first scenario too? Note that I can't remove first initialization, because it is unreachable for me. You can test this scenarios in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b6V3W/352/

Comment: Hello @Gab, I want to implement same, Have you found the solution? Please share here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For setting options **after initialization**, you need to use the **[`option()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option)** method.

```
$('#dater').datepicker( "option", "beforeShowDay", renderCalendarCallback );
```

**[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6V3W/370/)**

Comment: that is one hell of an alert loop you've got going on

Comment: I don't think this was the question, I think the question/problem is "beforeShowDay" is not run when datepicker initializes, it only runs on each day when something happens in the calendar. How one can trigger beforeShowDay after initialization?