# PHP AJAX Jquery calendar need to reset beforeShowDay values?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request that passes a large single array full of dates from a php file ("get-dates.php") after a drop-down box selection has been made.

The code I have now determines the available dates on the calendar based on the dates in the array that are passed back from the ajax JSON response. However if I re-select another drop down item It does not change to a new set of available dates.

Here is the code:

```
<option value="">Select Station</option>
<select name="station" class="form-control" id="station">
<?php 
    echo '<option value="'."1".'">'."1".'</option>';
    echo '<option value="'."2".'">'."2".'</option>';
    echo '<option value="'."3".'">'."3".'</option>';
?>
</select>
<p>Date: <input data-validation="date" data-validation-format="dd-mm-yyyy" id="datepicker" value="Pick Station" readonly="readonly"></p>
```

```js
function load_data(station) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"get-dates.php",
        method:"POST",
        //station is value of dropDown value selected
        data:{stationSelect:station},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("successful AJAX call");
            console.log(data);

            function available(date) {
                dmy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                if ($.inArray(dmy, data) != -1) {
                    return [true, "","Available"];
                } else {
                    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
                }
            }
            //calendar date selection
            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: available,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#station').change (function(){
        var station = $(this).val();
        if(station != '')
        {
            load_data(station);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the portion of code that calls this `load_data` function and relevant html?

Comment: @El_Vanja added :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery datepicker beforeShowDay after initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898008/jquery-datepicker-beforeshowday-after-initializing)

Comment: Also see [Reinitialize bootstrap datetimepicker with new format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783862/reinitialize-bootstrap-datetimepicker-with-new-format) and [jQuery UI Datepicker destroy and reinitialize calendar with new DefaultDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653043/jquery-ui-datepicker-destroy-and-reinitialize-calendar-with-new-defaultdate).